# How do I use an image multiple times in a OneNote document while storing the image only once?

Tags: deduplication, microsoft-onenote-2013

I'm using OneNote 2013 for family history.  I have created a page for each person with photos of and documents about that person.  In several cases I have group photos with many family members in them. If a photo has 14 people in it, I don't want to paste the image into 14 different pages - It would make my OneNote file unnecessarily huge.

Is there any way to have the same image file appear on multiple pages without each page having its own copy?  Or is OneNote smart enough to recognize it's the same file and optimize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ideas:
1: insert the photos as attachments. This would link to the photos in your pictures folder location. However, you might just see a photo icon, rather than a thumbnail on your OneNote page. If you rename the photo name, it would at least help you identify the icon on the OneNote page. Of course, if that source picture gets deleted or renamed, then the link would no longer work.
2: create a new folder, copy your desired pictures to that folder, and reduce their size by enough to make them smaller, but not so much as they get jaggy or blurry. Then insert those smaller pictures into your individual OneNote pages.
This method would give you a more reliable source for the photos, but reduce the bloat within OneNote, which of course, results in slower loading of that page.
You would need to decide the smaller vs. quality reduction amount.

Comment: Not what I was hoping for, but apparently the best solution.